# Как прописать редирект в .htaccess если изменился домен?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, домен, mod-rewrite, поддомены

Есть старый сайт на поддомене, например 2015.site.ru

поменяли основной домен site.ru на 2015.site.moscow

теперь нужно чтобы все обращения к 2015.site.ru переадресовывались на 2015.site.moscow

И естественно, не только обращения только к инденсу домена, но и любые другие, например чтобы http://2015.site.ru/images/pic.gif преобразовывался в http://2015.site.moscow/images/pic.gif

Однако при обращение к основному сайту site.ru не должно быть переадресации на site.moscow
Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое прописать в .htaccess?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

просто классика. скопировано из [ответа](https://serverfault.com/a/124490/292034):

```
rewriteengine on
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.example\.com
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://b.example.com/$1 [r,l]
```

---

доп. информация: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite

Answer (score 2):

Если ограничиваться только протоколом `HTTP`, то необходимый редирект можно записать, например, так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2015\.site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://2015.site.moskow/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Если надо таким же образом перенаправлять и протокол `HTTPS`, то правило будет немного посложнее:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2015\.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://2015.site.moskow/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2015\.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://2015.site.moskow/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Это правило понятно, но избыточно и сделано слишком прямолинейно. Можно его оптимизировать, убрав повторяющиеся элементы. В результате получится следующее:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=protocol:http]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=protocol:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2015\.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:protocol}://2015.site.moskow/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Интересно, что мне не удалось найти онлайн-тестер файла `.htaccess`, понимающий последний вариант. Но "живой" Apache обработал его корректно.